# How to most efficiently switch around elements in one ndarray based on another ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm having trouble figuring out how to efficently create a copy of a 3d numpy array where a small number of the elements are swapped around.

I'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
#the matrix to rearange 
a=np.array(
 [[[ 0,  1,  2],
    [ 3,  4,  5],
    [ 6,  7,  8]],

   [[ 9, 10, 11],
    [12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17]],

   [[18, 19, 20],
    [21, 22, 23],
    [24, 25, 26]]])

#a matric of indicies in a. In this case, [0,1,0] -> [0,0,0] -> [0,2,1] and all the rest are the the same
b=np.array(
[[[[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2]],
  [[0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2]],
  [[0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 2]]],

[[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2]],
 [[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2]],
 [[1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2]]],

[[[2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2]],
 [[2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2]],
 [[2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]]])

>>>np.something(a,b,whatever)
>>>np.array(
 [[[ 3,  1,  2],
   [ 7,  4,  5],
   [ 6,  0,  8]],

   [[ 9, 10, 11],
    [12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17]],

   [[18, 19, 20],
    [21, 22, 23],
    [24, 25, 26]]])
```

I'm also open to having b be full of indicies in the flattened version of a instead of coordinate vectors, but I'm still not sure how/if it could work efficiently.

Alternatively, if there's a way to make this work, the transformation matrix could be encoded with unit translations like this:

```
#the matrix to rearange 
a=np.array(
  [[[ 0,  1,  2],
    [ 3,  4,  5],
    [ 6,  7,  8]],

   [[ 9, 10, 11],
    [12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17]],

   [[18, 19, 20],
    [21, 22, 23],
    [24, 25, 26]]])

 #a transformation matric showing the same [0,1,0] -> [0,0,0] -> [0,2,1], but in terms of displacement. 
#In other words, the data in [0,0,0] is moved down 2 rows and right 1 column to [0,2,0], because b[0,0,0]=[0,2,1]
b=np.array(
[[[[0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, -1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, -1, -1], [0, 0, 0]]],

 [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]],

 [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]])


>>>np.something(a,b,whatever)
>>>np.array(
  [[[ 3,  1,  2],
    [ 7,  4,  5],
    [ 6,  0,  8]],

   [[ 9, 10, 11],
    [12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17]],

   [[18, 19, 20],
    [21, 22, 23],
    [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Comment: Can you explain how the value in your `b` array are supposed to swapp the element's position of the `a` array ?

Comment: Are you looking for basic fancy indexing?

Comment: I added comments for clarity. Can fancy indexing work in 3d like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Using your first version of `a` and `b`) You are looking for

```
a[tuple(np.moveaxis(b,-1,0))]
```

this splits `b` into individual arrays, one for each dimension of `a` and then uses them to index into `a` by means of "advanced" or "fancy" indexing.

Please note that the `tuple` conversion is important here. It changes the way numpy interprets the indices by telling it to treat each element of the tuple as indexing into one dimension. Left as a single nd array instead it would have been read as all indexing into dimension `0`. Try it out to get a feel for it!